# Jqgrid pager not working with "local" dataType

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Does Jqgrid allow us to add pager which we are using dataType local and don't want the whole data to be loaded at once. I am trying to do the same without success. It only shows the first page and show Page 1 Of 1 on the pager when there are many more records to be displayed.

Comment: I haven't encountered this problem.  Could you show your `.jqGrid()` init code?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you fill the grid contain in the wrong way. Look at [the example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGrid.htm) to see how you can use `data` parameter of jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue. I have a "local" jqgrid setup and it's showing my data but the pager values aren't completely accurate. Until I figured out that I needed to muck with the 'localReader' property. On the jqgrid wiki I saw that the jsonReader can have functions that define how to get the page, records, etc. It also states that the localReader can do whatever the jsonReader does so I gave it shot. Here's what I am doing.

```
var grid = $('#table').jqGrid({
  datatype: 'local',
  altRows: true,
  colModel: [
    {name: '0', label: "Name"},
    {name: '1', label: "Color"},
  ],
  pager: "#pager",
  rowNum: 15,
  sortname: '0',
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  height: '100%',
  autowidth: '100%'
});

var reader = {
  root: function(obj) { return results.rows; },
  page: function(obj) { return results.page; },
  total: function(obj) { return results.total; },
  records: function(obj) { return results.records; },

grid.setGridParam({data: results.rows, localReader: reader}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

My "results" is an object like this:

```
{page: "1", total: "70", records: "1045", rows:[.....]}
```

This seems to work as desired.